# How to fetch from this JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

here's the JSON file

```
[{
"Pizza": [
  {
    "title": "cheese lovers",
    "photo": "./cl.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "checken ranch",
    "photo": "./cr.jpg"
  }
],
"Pasta": [
  {
    "title": "spaghetti",
    "photo": "./sp.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "lasagna",
    "photo": "./la.jpg"
  }
],
"Asian": [
  {
    "title": "sushi",
    "photo": "sushi.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "chicken sweet & sour",
    "photo": "css.jpg"
  }
],
"Dessert": [
  {
    "title": "cheesecake",
    "photo": "cc.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "ice ceam",
    "photo": "ic.jpg"
  }
],
"Drinks": [
  {
    "title": "tea",
    "photo": "tea.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "orange juice",
    "photo": "oj.jpg"
  }
]
```

}
]

What I wanna do is using the fetch API the categories would be listed in a menu, and the inside content would be shown in other HTML elements. When I use a normal fetch API function I can see everything in the console, but when I try to render the JSON data it only shows [object object], any deeper levels give me errors.
So is there a different way I can fetch the data or the JSON file itself needs editing?

Comment: Please edit your post and include the code used to re-create the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot render an object directly into HTML, for example if you want to render your fetched API into HTML Lists you can do it like this:

```js
const a = [{
  "Pizza": [{
      "title": "cheese lovers",
      "photo": "./cl.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "checken ranch",
      "photo": "./cr.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "Pasta": [{
      "title": "spaghetti",
      "photo": "./sp.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "lasagna",
      "photo": "./la.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "Asian": [{
      "title": "sushi",
      "photo": "sushi.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "chicken sweet & sour",
      "photo": "css.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "Dessert": [{
      "title": "cheesecake",
      "photo": "cc.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "ice ceam",
      "photo": "ic.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "Drinks": [{
      "title": "tea",
      "photo": "tea.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "orange juice",
      "photo": "oj.jpg"
    }
  ]
}];
list = document.getElementById("ul"); //get access to your ul tag

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(a[0])) { //a[0] since you have the first layer is an array with one item

  let li = document.createElement("li"); // you map through your object and create an li tag

  li.innerText = key; // add the key text to the li ("Pizza", "Pasta", "Asian" ...)

  list.appendChild(li); // add the list item to the list

  let smallerList = document.createElement("ul"); //create another list (nested list)

  li.appendChild(smallerList); // add the nested list under the first list item

  value.forEach((element) => { //since its an array we map through it using array.forEach which means element is {"title": some data, "photo": some data}

    for (const [key2, value2] of Object.entries(element)) { //so we find that it is another object so we map through it

      let smallerLi = document.createElement("li"); // create another list item

      smallerLi.innerText = `${key2}: ${value2}`; // set the text of the list item to for example ("title": "orange juice")

      smallerList.appendChild(smallerLi); //add the smaller list item to the nested list

    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <ul id="ul">
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot console.log an object directly. One quick solution to debug (I assume you're trying to debug using console.log) is this

`console.log(JSON.stringify(data)`.

Another options for quick inspection are `console.table(data)` for table formatting or `console.dir(data)` to see all properties of your object.

Comment: Of course one can `console.log` an object directly?

Comment: Sure, my bad, I was thinking on resolving the promise if he is fetching the json. If he's not using promises, it's like an object.